# mysql insertion error for an integer data

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7

I have a database

```
raw_data(
Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra, id
'tweet_no', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'user_id', 'varchar(50)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'text', 'varchar(200)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'senti_score', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
 )
```

tweet_no is the primary key
What I am trying to do is retriving text and tweet_no of all rows. Analyse the text and insert the score so calculated back to the database.Please see the code below:

```
 import mysql.connector  
 cnx=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='root' ,database='db')

cursor = cnx.cursor()
cu_insert = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT text, tweet_no FROM raw_data")

cursor.execute(query)

for (text,tweet_no) in cursor:
tweet = str(text)
no = int(tweet_no)

print(no)
print(':::')
print(tweet)
print('\n')
print(preprocess(tweet))
```

Upto here my code works as I am able to fetch the data and process it.

```
  score=0

for term in terms_stop:
  if term in scores.keys():     #Look up each token in the scores dict
    print(term)
    print(scores[term])
    score = score + int(scores[term])           #If the term matches, assign the term score and calculate the total score of each tweet

else:
    score = score

print('..............')
print(score)
print('..............')

addto_raw_data=("INSERT INTO raw_data(senti_score) WHERE tweet_no=no VALUES(%s)",(score))
cu_insert.execute(addto_raw_data)

print('inserted')


cnx.commit()

cursor.close()

cu_insert.close()

cnx.close()
```

While trying to execute this part of code to insert score into senti_score column of above described database I am getting an error.

> raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found.")
>   mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found.

Please suggest how I can insert the score calculated into senti_score column of database using tweet_no which I am able to retrive. Is there any other method for insertion of score which I can use here like appending scores to a list and then inserting them.

Comment: Can you have a go at adding: cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True) and cu_insert = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

Comment: sorry it doesn't work as later i came to know where clause doesn't work with insert rather i have to use update

Comment: buffered=true was also needed, thanks for informing.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:

    update_raw_data=("UPDATE raw_data SET senti_score=%s WHERE tweet_no=%s ",(score,no))
    cu_insert.execute(*update_raw_data)
    print('inserted the score')

    cnx.commit()


except mysql.connector.Error as err:
     print(err.msg)
```